# Shouldautorotate returning wrong value

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I just tried adding some print statements to my shouldautorotate method and noticed that it checks it 4 times which does make sense but even though I am not switching mode from portrait to landscape,

it returns portrait 3 times and on the fourth time, it returns landscape even though my simulator is not in landscape.

```
if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
   NSLog(@"landscape left");
  }else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
   NSLog(@"landscape right");
  }else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){
   NSLog(@" portrait");
  }else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){
   NSLog(@"portrait upsidedown");
  }
```

Any one knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting that code into the `didAutorotate` or the `willAutorotate` method. `shouldAutorotate` is only supposed to return YES or NO.

I'm theorising that `shouldAutorotate` is checked regularly, whereas `didAutorotate` is only fired of when it detects an orientation shift.

This is the code I use to check:

```
- (void) reOrient{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation)){  

    } else {

    }
}
```

That is in a method I created called `reOrient` which is called from my `didAutorotate`

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    [self reOrient];
}
```

Just make sure when you create a new method like reOrient that you declare it in the header as well (I kept forgetting when I was starting out) as below:

```
- (void)reOrient;
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I am trying to find that method in the documentation.

Comment: if your using X-code, start typing - (void)didAutorotate... and the rest of it'll appear. You don't need to do anything as this is a built in method and so fires automatically. The reOrient method was a custom one I created, specific to my application and features the above if statement.